# stoping a loop iteration until time out and then resume

Tags: javascript

I am at a very beginning  stage of Javascript and got stuck with a loop.

Below given is a function which is expected to some thing like  `hi andy` then it should *wait for 3sec* and then welcome .Again `hi john` *wait for 3sec* and then welcome.

```
async SayHI(){
   var idList=['andy','john','mike','james']
   for await(const value of idList){  
   alert("hi" + value);
   setTimeout(()=>{alert("Welcome")},3000) 
 }
}
```

but it is displaying all the names in a sequence and then welcome after some time . though it is alerting welcome also for three times but not in the expected sequence.

Comment: You may want to try generators.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In pure javascript you can make use of recursion as show below

```
function sayHi(i,arr){
    if(arr[i]){
        alert("Hi "+arr[i]);
        setTimeout(()=>{alert("welcome");sayHi(i+1,arr)},3000)
    }
}
sayHi(0,["A", "B", "C", "D", "E"]);
```

asked question code does not work as for await resolves Iterable asynchronously and not the for await body, hence settimeout is executed via event loop while the forawait proceed in event stack

Answer (score 3):

You are looking for [`setInterval`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowOrWorkerGlobalScope/setInterval) function and not [`setTimeout`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowOrWorkerGlobalScope/setTimeout).

> The setInterval() method, offered on the Window and Worker interfaces, repeatedly calls a function or executes a code snippet, with a fixed time delay between each call. It returns an interval ID which uniquely identifies the interval, so you can remove it later by calling clearInterval().

See example

```js
var idList = ['andy', 'john', 'mike', 'james'],
    i = 0;

var interval = setInterval(() => {
  console.log("Welcome " + idList[i]);
  (++i >= idList.length) && clearInterval(interval);
}, 3000)
```

Your code is not working as you well, because the setTimeout into your loop is executed in a separate scope. So after the end of your loop, all setTimeout are started at the same time.

Answer (score 1):

It is not really usefull to use alertBoxes for that task, because it can mess up your timing and in the worst case block your user from any interaktions...

**Do it with a Element instead. Below is a possible solution with a div container:**

```js
function runWelcome(index) {
  /// make sure index is a number
  var index = Number(index);
  
  /// your id list
  var idList = ['andy','john','mike','james'];
  
  /// define the target for the output
  var msgBox = document.getElementById('msgBox');
  
  /// show message hi + XXX
  msgBox.innerHTML = 'hi '+idList[index];
  
  /// execute after 3 seconds
  setTimeout(function(){msgBox.innerHTML = 'Welcome'},3000);
  
  /// increase index
  index++;
  
  /// stop at the end of the idList
  if(index === idList.length){return};
  
  /// repeat after 6sec (3sec + 3sec = 6sec)
  setTimeout(function(){runWelcome(index)},6000);
  
};
```

```html
<div id='msgBox' style="width:100%; padding:20px;background-color:rgba(60,60,60,1); color:white;text-align:center;font-family:verdana;box-sizing:border-box">click start</div>
<input type="button" value="start" onClick="runWelcome(0)">
```